# Consulta por rango de fechas con muchas consultas anidadas

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo que obtener una lista con los clientes de la empresa a los que hemos facturado algo durante el presente año, indicando cuánto hemos facturado cada mes.

Tengo dos tablas: la tabla de clientes (customer) y la tabla de facturas (invoice). La relación es la evidente: un cliente puede tener muchas facturas, y cada factura está relacionada con un único cliente.

Lo único que se me ha ocurrido es lo siguiente:

```
select id, 
name as "Nombre",
identity_number as "CIF", 
(select sum(total) 
    from invoice 
    where payment_date between '2017-01-01' and '2017-02-01' and customer_id=c.id group by customer_id) as "Enero",
(select sum(total) 
    from invoice 
    where payment_date between '2017-02-01' and '2017-03-01' and customer_id=c.id group by customer_id) as "Febrero",
(select sum(total) 
    from invoice 
    where payment_date between '2017-03-01' and '2017-04-01' and customer_id=c.id group by customer_id) as "Marzo",
(select sum(total) 
    from invoice 
    where payment_date between '2017-04-01' and '2017-05-01' and customer_id=c.id group by customer_id) as "Abril",
(select sum(total) 
    from invoice 
    where payment_date between '2017-05-01' and '2017-06-01' and customer_id=c.id group by customer_id) as "Mayo",
(select sum(total) 
    from invoice 
    where payment_date between '2017-06-01' and '2017-07-01' and customer_id=c.id group by customer_id) as "Junio",
(select sum(total) 
    from invoice 
    where payment_date between '2017-07-01' and '2017-08-01' and customer_id=c.id group by customer_id) as "Julio",
(select sum(total) 
    from invoice 
    where payment_date between '2017-08-01' and '2017-09-01' and customer_id=c.id group by customer_id) as "Agosto",
(select sum(total) 
    from invoice 
    where payment_date between '2017-09-01' and '2017-10-01' and customer_id=c.id group by customer_id) as "Septiembre",
(select sum(total) 
    from invoice 
    where payment_date between '2017-10-01' and '2017-11-01' and customer_id=c.id group by customer_id) as "Octubre",
(select sum(total) 
    from invoice 
    where payment_date between '2017-11-01' and '2017-12-01' and customer_id=c.id group by customer_id) as "Noviembre",
(select sum(total) 
    from invoice 
    where payment_date between '2017-12-01' and '2017-12-31' and customer_id=c.id group by customer_id) as "Diciembre"
from customer c
where c.branding_id=1 and (select sum(total) 
    from invoice 
    where payment_date between '2017-01-01' and '2017-12-31' and customer_id=c.id group by customer_id) > 0
```

Esto funciona, pero lo encuentro extremadamente ineficiente (hay 13 subconsultas, si incluimos la del WHERE). ¿Hay algún modo de simplificar esta consulta o es la mejor forma de obtener los datos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basado en la respuesta de @amenadiel (que es correcta para MySQL), he creado la siguiente consulta:

```
select c.id, 
c.name as "Nombre",
c.identity_number as "CIF", 
  SUM(CASE WHEN date_part('month',i.payment_date)=12 then total else 0 end ) as diciembre,
  SUM(CASE WHEN date_part('month',i.payment_date)=11 then total else 0 end) as noviembre,
  ...
  SUM(CASE WHEN date_part('year',i.payment_date)=2017 then total else 0 end) as TOTAL
from customer c join invoice i on c.id=i.customer_id
where date_part('year',i.payment_date)=2017 and c.branding_id=2
group by c.id
order by c.id
```

Como curiosidad, la consulta de la pregunta necesitaba casi dos minutos en ejecutarse mientras que esta solución tarda alrededor de 300ms en mostrar los mismos resultados

Comment: La mejora en rendimiento es normal, y es porque en vez de recorrer la tabla `invoice` 12 veces por registro, solo lo recorres una vez en el join. Una gran diferencia. Si quieres mejorar el rendimiento aun más, modificaría la condición `where date_part('year',i.payment_date)=2017` a `where i.payment_date >= '2017-01-01' and i.payment_date < '2018-01-01'`. Esto permitiría el uso de índice en la columna `payment_date` si la tienes definida. Usando `date_part('year', i.payment_date)`, no es posible usar un indíce en esa columna.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT: después de redactar esta respuesta (para MySQL) me di cuenta de que la pregunta era en PostgreSQL. La sintaxis correcta está en la respuesta del OP.**

Primero, la cláusula final (que la suma de pagos de enero a diciembre de 2017 sea mayor a cero) es lo mismo que decir que `payment_date` sea del año 2017.

Segundo, suponiendo que tu tabla invoice es y contiene:

```
create table invoice (customer_id integer, total integer, payment_date datetime);
insert into invoice values (1, 5, now());
insert into invoice values (1, 15, NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY);
insert into invoice values (1, 45, NOW() - INTERVAL 41 DAY);
insert into invoice values (1, 12, NOW() - INTERVAL 61 DAY);
insert into invoice values (1, 13, NOW() - INTERVAL 91 DAY);
insert into invoice values (2, 55, now());
insert into invoice values (2, 15, NOW() - INTERVAL 21 DAY);
insert into invoice values (3, 145, NOW() - INTERVAL 71 DAY);
insert into invoice values (3, 1, NOW() - INTERVAL 16 DAY);
insert into invoice values (3, 3, NOW() - INTERVAL 121 DAY);
```

puedes ir haciendo en cada columna:

```
SUM(IF(MONTH(payment_date)=1, total, 0) as enero
```

Esto quedaría algo como:

```
select customer_id,
  SUM(IF(month(payment_date)=12,total,0)) as diciembre,
  SUM(IF(month(payment_date)=11,total,0)) as noviembre,
  SUM(IF(month(payment_date)=10,total,0)) as octubre,
  SUM(IF(month(payment_date)=9,total,0)) as septiembre,
  SUM(IF(month(payment_date)=8,total,0)) as agosto
from invoice
where year(payment_date)=2017
group by customer_id
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No incluí todos los meses ni el JOIN con la tabla de clientes, esa parte te la dejo de tarea, pero **si quieres listar todos los clientes, incluyendo los que no pagaron nada este año**, el `FROM` tendría que ser

```
FROM customer c LEFT JOIN invoice on customer_id=c.id AND YEAR(payment_date)=2017
```

[Fiddle de ejemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d824cd3/1)

Comment: Tu respuesta me ha sido útil para encontrar muchas mejoras, pero no sé para qué DBMS está escrita porque he tenido que buscar el equivalente a muchos detalles: no hay IF(..) o month(...) o year(...)en postgresql 9.4

Comment: Esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70104/discussion-on-answer-by-amenadiel-consulta-por-rango-de-fechas-con-muchas-consul) por petición del autor de la pregunta.